# What should an underground shelter, bunker or “regular” home look like if it’s designed to keep two people isolated for at least two years?

Tags: apocalypse, science-in-society, viruses

I’m asking this question because I was just thinking of how people would actually survive in the medium term in an apocalypse scenario with “reasonable and realistic” limits. The key world being reasonable and realistic. I don’t really expect to go full on fallout vault but I am curious to know what kind of house, bunker or home should be able to keep two people locked inside it for up to two years. The characters in question saw the problem coming about two to four months in advance and took a lot of steps to prepare for the next collapse of society.

Let me explain a bit about my situation or scenario and pardon me if it hits too close to home with the COVID situation. Unless otherwise assume it's covid but worse

In this case the two people, in question, are locked inside of a home for about a year because they’re worried about how the new apocalyptic pandemic would affect them. The person planning this saw the whole situation coming through a dream or prophecy before it actually got out of hand a few months before it reached their city. This is because, even though, they knew that their city and country would do most of the things to keep the disease away from their shores, it would be impossible to do so in the long run; especially if the disease kept burning through the population.
For those wondering the characteristics of the disease is as follows:

1. Mortality rate of 21.5% (i.e. nearly 1 in people who get it die)
2. Incubation period of 140 days (you can still have it and spread it after 140 days)
3. The Disease is Virus Based
4. The Virus is naturally created and can be transmitted to humans via the air and water or via human transmission
5. It's resistant to cold and hot weather
6. It has an R0 Value of 25 (i.e on person can spread it to 25 people)
7. The disease causes Skin Lesions, Necrosis, Total Organ Failure, Insanity, Hemorrhagic Shock and Dysentery
8. It takes about two years for vaccine to be produced as the virus keeps mutating

However this entire situation takes a while to do. I want my two characters, who managed to bunker down, to survive the next two years as the problems start to arise in this pandemic style apocalypse. At the present they're mostly just spent about a million dollars, to actually make such a bunker/home/shelter and will just be trying to survive in it for two years. They also live in a first world country about I expect that about 2-3% of the population in their nation is about to get killed every year due to the situation at hand.

Nevertheless in this case I wanted to just know, what should such a house or home look like for these to characters if they had two to four months to plan?

Comment: There are many different possible designs bunkers, shelters or houses. Even if you only consider the designs that are sufficient to survive 2 years in your specific apocalypse, this question has far too many equally valid answers to be a good fit for this site. Instead of asking us to do a requirements analysis for you, can you try doing a requirements analysis yourself and ask us for help resolving any specific problems you encounter during your process. Otherwise you're effectively asking us to build your world for you.

Comment: VTC: (a) Too story-based (aka, too opinion-based). (b) Not about worldbuilding according to the [help] (we don't answer questions about character choices. What to put in the bunker is the character's choice.) (c) If by "looks like" you mean the color of the paint on the wall, that's an off-topic aesthetic. If by "looks like" you mean something like "furnished" or "equipped," you need to say that. However, see (b). Remember we'll help you build your world, but not tell your story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on the British WWII plans for [Operation Tracer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Tracer). They had planned something like your requirement, with the added complication of Nazi soldiers overhead, and the big help of being able to get military supplies.

Or perhaps about long-term arctic/antarctic bases early in the last century. They had the added climate problem, but the equipment list gives a ballpark.

Consider the expense of the necessary supplies. How many people have two years' worth of spending money at hand? Of course they could take a mortgage, secure in the knowledge that the banking system would break under the pandemic. But how certain are they of the dream?

- **Food supply**
  In many urban, industrialized areas, people have an *unbalanced* food supply for a few days at most. They tend to go to the grocery, or order food deliveries, each day. What they have in their pantry might carry them for a few **days** -- pasta and tomato sauce for breakfast, lunch, and dinner -- but no longer. Survival for two **years** requires *balanced* food supplies with a *long* shelf life.
  As an approximation, a human needs perhaps 1 kg of food per day if some of that are dry staples (rice, pasta, dried beans) and water can be added. Two people, two years, **more than one ton** of food in the pantry. Normal people don't even come close, and as the pandemic looms supermarkets would run low. So they would have to have been the more paranoid sort of [prepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivalism) beforehand, or get that dream early and act on it immediately.
- **Water supply**
  That depends on the climate, but counting minimal hygiene needs there will be several dozen liters per person per day. Call it 35 metric tons, 35 cubic metres. Stowing that much is impractical, so they need a well and filtration.
- **Power**
  They might be able to use muscle power (hand pumps, bicycle generators, etc.) to replace electricity, even if that won't be fun. But how are they going to cook? Food that does not need cooking would increase bulk even more. How are they going to wash clothes?
- **Medical**
  Consider how often the average person goes to a doctor. Often this diagnoses and treats problems early, before they become serious issues. (If you know about the US health system, consider how much trouble it gets because under-insured people wait until they need the emergency room.) For that matter, just hope they have enough *toothpaste* for two people and two years ...
  Another medical issue the the balance of the diet. No *fresh* food for two years? They'd better have vitamin supplements, etc., to replace that.
- **Waste disposal**
  If they are in their bunker, the sanitary disposal of human and other wastes will be a problem. Are they connected to a working sewer?
- **Clothing, etc.**
  I guess that much can be stockpiled.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing any physical threat and thus no reason for a bunker.  Given that, I would have no problem doing this for half your budget:

Outside town somewhere buy a house.  An ordinary house.  Key requirements are that it has a well and a septic system.  Install an **off-grid** solar system sufficient to handle all loads, since you need redundancy make sure there multiple strings of batteries in the system.  Prepper stores will sell all the food etc that you're going to need to wait it out.

Given the additional budget (which is probably going to be useless after it's over) I would buy spares for important things.

Realistically, though, your disease has a long term fatality rate of almost 100%.  The grid will not survive losing that many people and without it we are thrown way, way back on the technological scale, the carrying capacity of the Earth is a tiny fraction of it's current population.